# Rubik's cube function

Tags: functions, rubiks-cube

I'm thinking in a function and if it's possible to solve that.

I have been playing with the cube using the following move: $R U L' U'.$

I notice that the cube solves itself with a certain number of moves: **28 moves** to $2\times2\times2$ and **112** to $3\times3\times3.$ (If the cube already is solved).

Then I'm trying to create a formula to calculate the number of moves for the another cubes like $4\times4\times4, 5\times5\times5, 6\times6\times6\dots$

Since:

> $x \rightarrow y$
>
> $1 \rightarrow 0$
>
> $2 \rightarrow 28$
>
> $3 \rightarrow 112$
>
> $4 \rightarrow z$

Where **x** is the number of the cube $(2 = 2\times2\times2, 3 = 3\times3\times3 \dots)$ and **y** is the amount of moves, I came up with two formulas: **28*$((x-1)^{(x-1)})$** and **28*$(x-1)^2$**. Thus, the value for $z$ could be **252** or **756**,

My questions are:

1. Are any of these formulas correct? If so, which one?
2. Can be my reasoning corret about the formulas?
3. If I'm wrong, answer me why!

Comment: Are R, U, L' turns of the outermost faces only (1 layer deep) as in Singmaster notation?

Comment: It must be the case: if you turn the 2 outermost layer of an $n\times n\times n$, it behaves like an $(n-1)\times (n-1)\times (n-1)$

Comment: Are you saying that f(n) is the order of RUL′U′ in the action group of n x n x n? if so, why isn't f(1) = 1?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The answer for a $4 \times 4 \times 4$, $5\times 5\times 5$, and so on cube will continue to be $112$.

Here's why. Imagine that you take an $n \times n \times n$ cube and, on each face, glue the pieces in the middle $(n-2) \times (n-2)$ square together, so they cannot be separated. Similarly, glue the middle $n-2$ pieces along each edge together. What you have is no longer an $n \times n \times n$ cube, but a $3 \times 3 \times 3$ cube in which some of the pieces are much larger in size. But it still operates exactly like a $3 \times 3 \times 3$ cube and affords exactly the same twists.

Your repeated `RULU'` move is acting on the $n \times n \times n$ cube in a way that gluing the pieces as above doesn't forbid. So whatever happens on the $n \times n \times n$ cube for $n>3$ is exactly the same as what happens for the $3 \times 3 \times 3$ cube.

The only reason that the $2 \times 2 \times 2$ cube is an exception is that here, there are no "edge" pieces at all. So if a sequence of moves in the $3 \times 3 \times 3$ cube scrambles (or flips) the edges but leaves the corners fixed, then on the $2 \times 2 \times 2$ cube, it does nothing, and this exactly describes what $28$ iterations of `RULU'` do.

Comment: Thanks a lot Misha!

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried it on a $4\times4\times4$ cube?  If not there are online rubiks cubes you can play around with.

But to answer your question my guess is that for any cube size $3$ and up you'll solve it again in $112$ moves.  That is because R U L' U' doesn't touch any of the "inner" edges so that means larger cubes will all behave like a $3\times3\times3$ cube in this case.

Answer (score 2):

What if the middle squares in a $4\times4\times4$ are scrambled?

Here's a couple more resources to help you with your mathematical journey. A full analysis of the Rubiks Cube, based on a 2-week long summer Research Experience for Undergraduates, can be found [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~jjchen/docs/Group%20Theory%20and%20the%20Rubik%27s%20Cube.pdf). In particular, you found what's called a *group generator*. The number of steps is the [*order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) of the group element (distinct from the order of the group itself).